# Initial zoom level with Seadragon export

Tags: export, gephi, seadragon

Lately I've encountered and issue. When I export my graphs from Gephi with a Seadragon plugin, First zoom level is far way back, e.i. on first zoom levels it's not even visible, on 5th zoom level whole graph take something like 10 pixels in diameter. PNGs are being exported in a proper way. Yesterday Seadragon export was working fine. Any ideas how to fix that?

So for example for tile size 200px this is the only file in `map_files/8` (called `0_0.png`)
[image]

The image is `156 x 156`. So you can barely see image at zoom level 8 (first zoom level is 0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Seadragon (Deep Zoom) format specifies that the pyramid should go all the way down to 1 pixel at zoom level 0. Level 1 should be 2 pixels wide, level 2 should be 4, etc. Sounds like it was working correctly.

Of course when you display the image, you need to pick the level that works for your current display size, rather than starting at the tip of the pyramid.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me is removing Gephi (with conf files) and reinstalling it.

Sadly I still don't know what was the problem